# How do I post on a django model when it has another model (manytomany ) inside nested serializers, I want at the same time to create both

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, rest, django-models

My models are:

1. Period
2. ClassStudentSubject

Period has a manytomany relationship with ClassStudentSubject

When I POST a period I don't want to choose which existing ClassStudentSubject object I use, I want to create a new one together with the period.

ClassStudentSubject - I created this model for the sake of structuring some data of period into an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by overriding create method of the serializer. You have to create "ClassStudentSubject" object first and then use that object while creating Period object in "create" method.
Here is the below example from the doc suiting your requirement.

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ['order', 'title', 'duration']

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['album_name', 'artist', 'tracks']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tracks_data = validated_data.pop('tracks')
        album = Album.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for track_data in tracks_data:
            Track.objects.create(album=album, **track_data)
        return album
```

Comment: This solved my problem. I am able to post from Album with the track, but what I am not able to do is post on the fields that have ManyToMany relationship. Like in the case of Tracks if orders was a manytomany relationship with another object, I can post from Tracks with the array of ids of orders, but if I do it from the Album it will tell me: ield 'id' expected a number but got [<Orders: 2B>] where 2B is the value of name from the Orders model "returned def __str__(self) -> str:
        return (self.name)"

Comment: field 'id' expected a number but got [<Orders: 2B>]. You can resolve this by passing the id of the order object. For example, if i have to pass id of any Orders instance, I have to as below
Order_obj = Orders.objects.get(pk=1)
Order_obj.id  or Order_obj.<variable_name>  needs to be passed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70006315/i-am-trying-to-post-on-to-a-manytomany-relationship-field-via-a-model-where-the I posted the code here if you could have a look

Comment: Try creating order instance -> Album instance -> tracks without manytomanyfield. Then add Order instance to newly created tracks isntance.  As per the django doc,  "order" field of "Track" model should get a value after Track instance is saved. I am not sure, will this solve ur problem, but u can refer below doc and try in console before modifying serializers.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/