# I am trying to post on to a manytomany relationship field via a model where the model with the manytomany relationship is nested

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-serializer, manytomanyfield

When I try to post by using the get_or_create, and writable nested serializers, I can do that but the fields with many to many relationships somehow even though they are an array of ids when posted, I get the error:

TypeError at /Albums/
Field 'id' expected a number but got [<Order: 2B>].

the structure:
**Tracks have Orders** (where orders is a manytomany field of the class Orders)

**Album has Tracks**

I can post in tracks and mention the orders as an array "orders":[2,4]

When I try to post in the Album together with the Tracks, I can post the tracks with the fields that ARE NOT manytomany fields, but if I try with the manytomany fields I get the type error mentioned above.

2B is the value of another field and not the id of the Order, is the value of the field returned in the

```
  def __str__(self) -> str:
        return (self.name)
```

**Models:**

```
 class Orders(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title


class Tracks(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(default="Period Relationship",
                            max_length=100, blank=True)
    orders = models.ManyToManyField(Orders, blank=True)
    album = models.ForeignKey(
        Album, related_name="tracks", default=None, on_delete=CASCADE)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return (self.name)
```

**Serializers:**

```
class TracksSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Tracks
        fields = "__all__"

class Album(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TracksSerializar(
        many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ALbum
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tracks = validated_data.pop(
            'tracks')

        album = Album.objects.create(
            **validated_data)
        for tracks in tracks:
            Tracks.objects.get_or_create(
                album=album, **tracks)
            album.tracks.add(
                tracks)
        return album
class OrdersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 
    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Views:**

```
class OrdersViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def list(self, request):
        orders = Orders.objects.all()
        serializer = OrdersSerializer(
            orders, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = OrdersSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = Orders.objects.all()
        orders = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = OrdersSerializer(
            orders)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    def update(self, request, pk=None, **kwargs):
        partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        orders = Orders.objects.get(pk=pk)
        serializer = OrdersSerializer(
            orders, data=request.data, partial=partial)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['partial'] = True
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
        orders = Orders.objects.get(pk=pk)
        orders.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

class AlbumViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def list(self, request):
        album = Album.objects.all()
        serializer = AlbumSerializer(album, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = AlbumSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = Album.objects.all()
        album = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = AlbumSerializer(album)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def update(self, request, pk=None, **kwargs):
        partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        album = Album.objects.get(pk=pk)
        serializer = AlbumSerializer(
            album, data=request.data, partial=partial)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['partial'] = True
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
        album = Album.objects.get(pk=pk)
        album.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)



class TracksViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def list(self, request):
        tracks = Tracks.objects.all()
        serializer = TracksSerializaer(
            tracks, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = TracksSerializaer(
            data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = Tracks.objects.all()
        tracks = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = TracksSerializaer(
            tracks)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        tracks = Tracks.objects.get(
            pk=pk)
        serializer = TracksSerializaer(
            tracks, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
        tracks = Tracks.objects.get(
            pk=pk)
        tracks.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Comment: You may want to add the code of the models rather than just a general description. It looks like you're assigning an object when it is expecting an id. You can do `instance.pk` to return just the `id`.

Comment: @Bobort edited with the code, I used the code as a simplified example, as I have more fields involved but the solution will be the same

Comment: Well, I see issues with your `create` method in your `Album` serializer. You're looping through `tracks` with a variable name of `tracks` which is overwriting anything you put into it earlier. And you don't need to do an `add` on `album` since you already specified it in `get_or_create`. Take out the `for` and the `add` statement. I don't think it's THE fix, but it will get you closer. Also, why not use Django Rest Framework for all this serialization?

Comment: @Bobort removing the add works fine. but removing the for just gives me more issues like to not use direct assignment orders.set() and some not null constraint. I am new in Django but I thought I am using the Django Rest Framework, what am I doing wrong?
If I remove the for, what should be the second argument in the get_or_create?

Comment: Try creating order instance -> Album instance -> tracks without manytomanyfield. Then add Order instance to newly created tracks isntance.  As per the django doc,  "order" field of "Track" model should get a value after Track instance is saved. I am not sure, will this solve ur problem, but u can refer below doc and try in console before modifying serializers.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/